# Implementation swappable bottom sheet using React Swipe-able

Tags: reactjs, swipe

I am using [React Swipable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipeable) library and need swipping event to the bottom sheet on swipping up or down.

```
 import { useSwipeable, SwipeEventData } from 'react-swipeable';
  
 const handleSwiped = (eventData: SwipeEventData) => {
      console.log("Test", eventData);
 };

const handlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwiped: handleSwiped,
});

<button type="button" aria-label="handlebar" {...handlers} />
```

I am referring [example](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-swipeable/blob/main/examples/app/SimplePattern/pattern.tsx) can any body help me here?

Can anybody help to